# Multiple images uploader using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, image, file-upload

I want to create a PHP code which will upload multiple images. There is only one thing which I'm struggling with. I got the code to upload the images and all but the problem is a timeout of the browser. If i want to upload for example 250 images at the same time, it will start processing it until it will timeout and as a result not all of the images will be uploaded.

I was thinking for a while, and I thought that maybe if I can use `jQuery Ajax` I can send the images behind the scenes and upload them there and maybe I won't get the timeout error. I thought that way because uploading 1 image at a time shouldn't cause the timeout error, so if I can take all of the images, and through jQuery send them one by one to upload, it might work.

What do you think? Do you have any other suggestion? Keep in mind that I can upload 100 images at a time, or even 2000 images at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pluploader](http://www.plupload.com/) plugin, it is a great plugin and well suited for uploading multiple files which you can handle at your server-side script easily:

Here is an example code :

```
<!---------HTML ------------->

 <div id="uploader">
        <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
    </div>

  <!-------------JS -----------------> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize the widget when the DOM is ready
    $(function() {
        $("#uploader").plupload({
            // General settings
            runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
            url : "examples/upload",

            // Maximum file size
            max_file_size : '2mb',

            chunk_size: '1mb',

            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            resize : {
                width : 200,
                height : 200,
                quality : 90,
                crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
            },

            // Specify what files to browse for
            filters : [
                {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
                {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip,avi"}
            ],

            // Rename files by clicking on their titles
            rename: true,

            // Sort files
            sortable: true,

            // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
            dragdrop: true,

            // Views to activate
            views: {
                list: true,
                thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
                active: 'thumbs'
            },

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url : 'http://rawgithub.com/moxiecode/moxie/master/bin/flash/Moxie.cdn.swf',

            // Silverlight settings
            silverlight_xap_url : 'http://rawgithub.com/moxiecode/moxie/master/bin/silverlight/Moxie.cdn.xap'
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Do they have a documentation for jQuery? All I saw was documentation using raw JavaScript. In your example, you used jQuery, so is there a jQuery documentation?

Comment: Yea but it's not really a documentation, it's an example. I would like to know how to implement it and see all possible options.

Comment: Okay , here is the docs : http://www.plupload.com/docs/Options 
and demos page : https://github.com/jayarjo/plupload-demos/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks! do I have to write the server-side script for uploading? If I do, I guess that it's validating the file before sending it to upload right?

Comment: Yes exactly , using $_FILES['filename'] where filename is name of file you are sending!

Comment: Aditya, thanks! I couldn't accept it as an answer before because of the time limit. So basically, I got a class which uploads images so I just have to implement this class on an external php file, and just specify the location to that file on the `url` property. Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me for bothering you that much, but I have one last quesiton. The code that I will write for the upload, it should be designed for 1 image at a time? or it has to run through an array?

Comment: One at a time, so the same function will run for all the list of files